# Omitting article

Tags: articles

In the following sentence, do I need a "the" before assembly, and if yes, why?

> In a specific environment, workpieces are transported to the next position at
> a fixed rate, even if assembly is not yet complete.

Answer (score 1):

The article is *optional* in the cited context

Note that if you *don't* have the article, "assembly" here can *only* refer to ***the process of assembling***.

But if you *do* include the article, it's entirely a matter of interpretation whether "the assembly" refers to that process, OR to ***the assembled product itself***.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a typographical mistake in *pieces*, and I have corrected it.

*assembly* refers to the work on the pieces, and hence we need a determiner.  The possessive pronoun *their* could be more appropriate than the definite article *the*, which is also fine.

Also, the comma before *even* is not needed.

> In a specific environment, pieces are transported to the next position at a fixed rate even if *their* assembly is not yet complete.

Comment: "topological"?  I think there's a *typographical* error there!

Comment: @stangdon, you are right.   I myself made a typographical mistake.  I will correct it.